# SonarQube project specific configuration

Tags: java, plugins, settings, project, sonarqube

I'm working on a SonarQube plugin which sends Sonar analysis data to an dashboard. I want to do some configuration for specific projects in sonar. I know that you can configure global settings with the web interface. I can change global settings for a plugin but i really want to change settings with the web interface but for some specific projects.

I'm using Sonar 4.2. The API is saying that the project settings are on batch side and not on the server side.

> "Project settings on batch side, or global settings on server side." ([Sonar 4.2 Api](http://javadocs.sonarsource.org/4.2/apidocs/org/sonar/api/config/Settings.html))

Another solution is writing an JSON configuration file which is available to the plugin but i'm hoping to avoid this solution.

Does anybody know another solution for easy configuring project specific settings?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use Jenkins? http://qualilogy.com/en/install-sonarqube-sonarqube-analysis-with-jenkins/

I use it as an interface to manage all my analysis. Here is an example http://qualilogy.com/en/plsql-analysis-sonarqube-configuration/